# Assign value matrix based on index condition

Tags: r, function, matrix, indexing, apply

How can I **assign a value** into a **matrix** based in a vector **condition index**. A working example is:

```
# Input: 
r <- c(2, 1, 3)
m <- matrix(rep(0, 9), nrow = 3)

# Desired output
result <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0,
               1, 0, 0,
               0, 1, 0), nrow = 3)
result.

# I try with this notation but it does not work:
sapply(1:3, function(x)m[x, r[x]] <- 1)
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that you're doing the assignment within a function, so the change happens in the function's environment, which is separate from the global environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `row/column` indexing to assign

```
m[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m)), r)]  <- 1
```

---

Or using `replace`

```
replace(m, cbind(seq_len(nrow(m)), r), 1)
```